# How to integrate DocuSign into the Android app without login stuff

Tags: docusignapi

My purpose is to create a license document with all users information and after that give user possibility to sign it in the mobile app. Also, SMS recipient identity authentication should be added.

I've already tried Authorization Code, Implicit and JWT Grants. But all of them are needed consent obtaining (login process). And it's inappropriate solution for both backend and mobile app sides.

According to my purpose, PowerForm feature looks very good. But I've not found possibilities to receive a token and generate PowerForm on the fly by backend side without user interaction.

If somebody has a solution or something were missed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably hardcode the token needed for authentication on the server to generate the PowerForms and then on the mobile device - just open the link to the PowerForm. No authentication is required to sign a PowerForm, just to generate it, but you wouldn't need your end-users to generate it, I assume.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a good idea and I've already thought about it.
But I didn't find a possibility to generate the token without expiration time(.
And I didn't find API calls which give possibility to generate PowerForm on the server-side.
If it's possible, please attach documentation links for it.

Comment: here is the link to the reference for our PowerForm APIs - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/PowerForms/PowerForms/